# How to provide the security to my .sqlite file in assets folder?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my app i have use .sqlite database when zip my .apk file and extract this one my all code and database file also is came.How to provide the security to my database file and source code any one please give any suggestion.
Thank u in advice.

Comment: What do you mean with "security"?

Comment: no one see my database file and src code using .apk file

Comment: plz provide how to use proguard.

Answer (score 0):

So at a guess you are using a pre-populated SQLite database? You could use [SQLCipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher) to encrypt the database - it works with pre-populated and new ones created by the app.

Comment: Thanks.How to use SQLCipher give me any example.